# SQL combining or,and query

Tags: mysql

I have one table called student.I want to select a student name who is living in chennai or madurai and born on december 8 1996.The table column name is (name,city,DOB). Sort the result by name. I have written like this and i got error "Invalid relational operator".

```
SELECT name
FROM student
WHERE city='chennai' OR 'madurai' AND DOB='december 8 1996'
ORDER BY name;
```

Comment: You have incorrect syntax. This will work: `WHERE (city='chennai' OR city = 'madurai') AND DOB='december 8 1996'`

Comment: or use `where city IN ('chennai','madurai') AND DOB='december 8 1996'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to mention the column in each where clause test.

Also if you are mixing AND and OR you need to apply some parenthasis to ensure they are applied correctly.

Also the date should be in `yyyy-mm-dd` format Assuming that you have deined `DOB` as a DATE type. And you should have if it is holding a date.

```
SELECT name
FROM student
WHERE (city='chennai' OR city='madurai' ) AND DOB='1996-12-08'
ORDER BY name;
```